# Is there another way to allow USB debugging from VS Code and Android Studio

Tags: flutter, debugging

Launching lib\main.dart on SM A115F in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Nxshe Medan\Projects\flutter_application_1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Nxshe Medan\n.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Whenever I try USB debugging it is exiting with this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: does the app work on emulator?

Comment: have you tried it in other device?